# How to add SetPropertyActionListener correctly?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i use Primefaces 3.0.1 and build up a menubar with programmatically filled model. I need some Links like depotDetails.xhtml?**id=1** But if i use these URL for my menuitem

```
item.setUrl("depotDetail.xhtml?id=1"); // that dont work
```

so i tried to add an ActionListener:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ValueExpression target =     facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), "#{DepotBean.currentDepot}",String.class);
ValueExpression value = facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), "ehnemeneee",String.class);

ActionListener handler = new SetPropertyActionListenerImpl(target, value);

item.addActionListener(handler);
```

but that also dont work. Can anybody help?

Greets Thomas

Comment: what do you mean item.setUrl("depotDetail.xhtml?id=1"); // that dont work ?? url is not called or it does not contain any url or incomplete url?

Comment: have you tried item.setUrl("depotDetail.jsf?id=1");      ?

Comment: yes i tried it, but it only pass depotDetail.xhtml without parameter

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution ... but is it the right way?

```
// building the menu model ..

UIParameter param = null;  

for(Depots testdepot: depotList){
    param = new UIParameter();
    param.setName("currentDepotId");  
    param.setValue(testdepot.getIdDepot()); 

    item = new MenuItem();              
    item.setValue(testdepot.getDepotName());  
    // calling menuListener
    item.addActionListener(new MenuListener());            
    item.setUpdate("messages");
    item.setId("menuItemDepot"+testdepot.getIdDepot());
    item.getChildren().add(param);

    submenu.getChildren().add(item); 
}

// MenuListener
public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);

    // get param id
    String name = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("currentDepotId");  

    // set session var
    session.setAttribute("currentDepotId", name);   

    fc.getExternalContext().redirect(request.getContextPath() + "/userarea/depotDetail.xhtml");
}

// read the session in the depot bean
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
String currentDepotId = session.getAttribute("currentDepotId");
```